# Terminal in full screen mode: how do I recover from "cat /dev/random"

Tags: terminal, command-line, performance, macos

What are the ways I can regain control over my computer when I have terminal in full screen mode and type:

`cat /dev/random`

Comment: Why are you typing `cat /dev/random`?

Comment: @DanielLawson - I'm learning OSX and experimenting. I hope to learn how to recover from a runaway process, which may happen in a developer environment (which I'm in)

Comment: You can press the power button and hold it. The filesystem is journaled and you'll soon learn which programs don't save their files cleanly :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Terminal.app open anyway (doesn't matter whether it's in fullscreen mode or not):

- <kbd>Cmd-T</kbd> to create new tab/shell
- `ps aux | fgrep /dev/random` to find the running `cat` (you can grep for `cat` as well but there might be more than one matching line)
- `kill <PID from above>` (or `kill -9 <PID>`)

Just be patient, the system may be really slow (even on a multicore system as I've just found out).

Comment: Is "kill -9" a joke referring to 9 lives of a cat, or is it something else?

Comment: See `man kill`, -9 is the signal to send. By default, kill sends a "soft" termination (letting the application/command handle the termination itself). This may not work if the application is stuck in some loop and never gets to handle the signal. -9 terminates on OS level.

Comment: Would `killall cat` not work?

Comment: There might be several cats running through the (process) jungle, no reason to commit felinicide...

Comment: @makerofthings7 In general, you should at _least_ try `kill -TERM` or `kill -INT` (which is the same as `^C`) first; [jumping straight to `SIGKILL` is often a bad idea.](http://www.novosial.org/shell/kill-9/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this, type `control-c` in terminal, it should stop any running command.

Comment: Perhaps the keyboard buffer was still full for me... ctrl c had no effect

Comment: Really! I tried several times, and each time I was able to get out of 'cat' no problem.

Comment: I ended up going into activity monitor and killing the cat.  Fortunately I only had to do it once

Comment: Fair enough. Seems like a strange thing to do, but I've seen (much) worse before.

Comment: You might need to reset the terminal with command-R.